# PIL Gif generation not working as expected

Tags: python, discord.py, python-imaging-library

**What I'm trying to do**: Since I'm still quite new to image generation using the PIL library, I decided to experiment with putting images on top of gifs. There were not a lot of proper tutorials or references I could use.

**What's going wrong**: More often than not, the gif would not be generated. This would give the error `IndexError: bytearray index out of range` which I'm not sure how to fix. However, sometimes the gif would be generated, but there would be some errors. I have included some of these gifs below.

[image: Example1 of this not working]

[image: Example 2 of this not working]

**The code**:

```py
@client.command()
async def salt(ctx, user:discord.Member=None):
    if user == None:
        user = ctx.author

    animated_gif = Image.open("salty.gif")
    response = requests.get(user.avatar_url)
    background = Image.open(BytesIO(response.content))
    
    all_frames = []
#    background = background.resize((500, 500))

    for gif_frame in ImageSequence.Iterator(animated_gif):

        # duplicate background image
        new_frame = background.copy()  

        # need to convert from `P` to `RGBA` to use it in `paste()` as mask for transparency
        gif_frame = gif_frame.convert('RGBA')  

        # paste on background using mask to get transparency 
        new_frame.paste(gif_frame, mask=gif_frame) 

        all_frames.append(new_frame)
        
    # save all frames as animated gif
    all_frames[0].save("image.gif", save_all=True, append_images=all_frames[1:], duration=50, loop=0)
```

This is the gif I am using:

[image: Salty gif]

Comment: Here's a possibility.  GIFs technically do not have transparency.  Traditionally, whatever pixel is in the upper left corner is designated as the transparent color.  It looks like your frames have two different upper left pixels.  You might TRY forcing the upper left pixel to white.

Comment: Even if I could, I wouldn't really know how to do this.. Do you know what I could use to help push me in the right direction?

Comment: The information about picking transparency from the color of the first pixel is incorrect. The GIF89A spec allows for one transparent color index, which is explicit in the headers: http://giflib.sourceforge.net/whatsinagif/bits_and_bytes.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately animated GIF support in PIL is faulty, and hard to work with at all. The images you are showing suffer from the layers sharing the palette information with the background layer, so they have some of their colors distorted.

I don't know if there is a way to control the palette information for each frame using PIL.

If you want to generate GIFs progamaticaly using Python, I'd, for now, recommend that you use the GIMP Image editor - there you can build your image, either interactively using the program, or programaticaly, using the Python console, and just call the "save as gif" function (`pdb.file_gif_save2`).

(I will take a look at PILs exact capabilities, and check if I can extend the answer on proper handling of transparency - otherwise, GIMP is the way to go)